# Fail to receive message from Online MQTT Broker to Local Broker in Mosquitto Bride

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I have an Cloud MQTT in the Internet (such as test.mosquitto.org)
Besides that, I have an Wireless Sensor Network controlled by MQTT in local Broker at My laptop.

I want to control my network in anywhere by publish a message on my cloud MQTT, and then it repulish on my local broker.
So I used Mosquitto Bridge http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/mosquitto-bridge-configuration/

When I publish a message to local broker, it appear in my cloud mqtt, but otherwise not, sometimes new messages appear, sometimes it duplicate.
But 90% of the time it can't be delivered.

This is my mosquitto.conf

```
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

connection bridge
address test.mosquitto.org:1883
remote_clientid trannhoduc
topic nhoduc/ok/# both 2
```

Thanks for your help!

I have tried different brokers: test.mosquitto.org, broker.emqx.io but same result

Comment: What version of mosquitto are you running locally? And is there anything in the logs that might show the bridge connection being dropped?

Comment: Are you configuring both broker as bridge or one of them and which one?

Comment: @BrijeshVarsani the OP has no access to configure test.mosquitto.org or broker.emqx.io